# WPF Command execution sequencing

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a WPF application that uses MVVM pattern.  I have controls in the window that are bound to properties in the ViewModel.  I have a Play button that is bound to the Play() method via an ICommand interface implementation.  As the Play() method steps through, I first change some properties to alter the UI to show the user that the app is working:

```
IsPlaying = true;
IsNotPlaying = false;
DurationTimer.Start();

Status = $"Playing: {_playingUrl}";
FilePreview?.FileNameSet(_playingUrl, "");
FilePreview?.FilePlayStart();
```

When the Play button is pressed it should disable the Play button via the `IsPlaying` property and enable the Stop button via the `IsNotPlaying` property.  Also, the `DurationTimer` should start (which displays a timer) and the `Status` property.  These are intended, as said, to show the user that things are happening since `FilePreview?.FilePlayStart();` is a blocking method and the UI locks up while processing.

However, when the Play button is pressed the UI immediately locks and, then, once the FilePlayStart() method finishes its processing, it releases and the other items become effective.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I missing something?". You can't update the UI and execute a blocking method on the same thread simultaneously. You should execute the blocking method on a background thread and update your UI on the dispatcher (main) thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPF, like most of UI frameworks, updates the UI only from one single Thread (any attempt to update the UI from another Thread will raise a System.InvalidOperationException).

Now, since the UI Thread is busy executing your method, it cannot update the UI at the same time.

WPF works with "bulks" of code. Once a bulk is executed, the UI takes care of all the updates. AT THE END of the execution, not in the middle.

So, if in the `Execute` method (or any other method executed on the UI Thread) you set 40 times "can execute = true", "can execute = false", "can execute = true", "can execute = false", actually you won't see the `Button` being unabled and disabled 40 times. Instead, when the method exits, THEN the UI is updated with the last value.

So, how to solve this? The `Execute` method should be asynchronous.

Something like:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    //ICommad implementation and other stuffs
    //...

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await DoExecute(parameter);
    }

    private async Task DoExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //do something asynchronously...
    }
}
```

In your specific case, `FilePreview?.FilePlayStart();` should be asynchronous, and you should pass this method to the `Command`.
You can write a general `Command`:

```
public class Command : ICommand
{
    //ICommad implementation and other stuffs
    //...

    //pass the execution in the constructor
    public Command(Func<object, Task> execution)
    {
        _execution = execution;
    }

    private Func<object, Task> _execution;

    public async void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        await _execution(parameter);
    }

    private async Task DoExecute(object parameter)
    {
        //do something asynchronously... like await Task.Delay(2000);
    }
}
```

You can then use it this way in the owner of the `Command`:

```
MyCommand = new Command(async parameter => 
{
    IsPlaying = true;
    IsNotPlaying = false;
    await FilePreview?.FilePlayStartAsync();
});
```

As soon as the `await` part is entered, the execution pass to another Thread, and the current Thread (that is the UI Thread) is free to update the UI, and you will see that the `Button`s are enabled/disabled as you want.

If an async version of the method is not available, you can write:

```
MyCommand = new Command(async parameter => 
{
    IsPlaying = true;
    IsNotPlaying = false;
    await Task.Run(() => FilePreview?.FilePlayStart());
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, FilePreview is an object provided by a Third party SDK and it not available in an ASync version.

Answer (score 0):

You can't perform long running operations on the UI thread, as it will block the dispatcher until it is done processing.

In cases like this, just use async/await to free the dispatcher and allow message pumping to continue.

```
private async void PlayCommand()
{
    IsPlaying = true;
    IsNotPlaying = false;
    DurationTimer.Start();

    Status = $"Playing: {_playingUrl}";

    await Task.Run(()=>
    {
        FilePreview?.FileNameSet(_playingUrl, "");
        FilePreview?.FilePlayStart();
    });
}
```